# Please make sure your password match during User registration 1.9.2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.2.1

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
```

I found some answers that i must change: `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();` in `$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();` but I in my code I find well `$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();`

I tried to do the opposite, to change `$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();` in `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();` it works but there is a problem:

when I enter the informations and I submit, it redirects me to a blank page with this `url: http://www.domaine.com/customer/account/createpost/` and when I refresh the page it redirects me to `http : //www.domaine.com/customer/account/` with the dashboard and the created account.

anyone know why there is a blank page for the first url and how to fix this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `setConfirmation()` and `getConfirmation()` in your extensions and replace with `setPasswordConfirmation()` and `getPasswordConfirmation()`.

Or if they should stay compatible with older versions, use something like this:

```
$info = Mage::getVersionInfo();
$version = "{$info['major']}.{$info['minor']}.{$info['revision']}.{$info['patch']}";

if($version >= '1.9.1.0'){
$customer->setPasswordConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation')); // just check the name of confirm password field in the registration form accordlingly add the name in the get Post
} else {
$customer->setConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation')); // just check the name of confirm password field in the registration form accordlingly add the name in the get Post
}
```

Comment: I search  `setConfirmation()` and `getConfirmation()` in all files of my website and I replace them or just in: `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`.? I already do a search for `setConfirmation()` and have find Zero matches in all the files, but `getConfirmation()` i have found it in this files:

Comment: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account`

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php`

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php`

`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`

`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`

`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php`

`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php`

`code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`

for your 2nd solution i didnt understand where i put it